# Problems in connecting to the database and fetching data in Visual Studio Windows Form

Tags: c#, php, sql, winforms, visual-studio

I have a combo box that's supposed to output the main category (has 4 rows) then also output the sub category under it (ex. 3 sub categories under the first main category, 5 sub categories under the second main category and so on).

My First Code displays the main category correctly (the combobox has 4 results)

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
sc.Open();

//For Main Category
SqlCommand get_maincategory_name = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM maincategory", sc);
SqlDataReader dr2 = get_maincategory_name.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr2.Read())
    {
    comboBox1.Items.Add(dr2["maincategory_name"].ToString());
    }

sc.Close();
}
```

But I tried inserting another loop for the sub category under the while loop of the main category but all I'm getting on the combo box is the first row of the main category (the combobox only has 1 result which is the first row from the main category table)

The code I used was:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
sc.Open();

//For Main Category
SqlCommand get_maincategory_name = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM maincategory", sc);
SqlDataReader dr2 = get_maincategory_name.ExecuteReader();
    while (dr2.Read())
    {
    comboBox1.Items.Add(dr2["maincategory_name"].ToString());

    //For Sub Category
    int got_category_id = Convert.ToInt32(dr2["maincategory_id"]);
    SqlCommand get_subcategory_name = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE maincategory_id='got_category_id'", sc);
    SqlDataReader dr3 = get_subcategory_name.ExecuteReader();
        while (dr3.Read())
        {
        comboBox1.Items.Add(dr3["subcategory_name"].ToString());
        }
    }

sc.Close();
}
```

The only programming experience I have is on php so I tried creating my intended code on PHP and it worked perfectly but I'm having troubles applying it to C# in Visual Studio, here's my code if you guys are wondering what I'm trying to achieve:

```
echo "<select>";

// FOR MAIN CATEGORY
$maincategory_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM maincategory") or mysqli_error();
while($got = mysqli_fetch_assoc($maincategory_query))
{
$maincategory_id = $got['maincategory_id'];
$maincategory_name = $got['maincategory_name'];
echo "<option disabled>$maincategory_name</option>";

    // FOR SUB CATEGORY
    $subcategory_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE maincategory_id='$maincategory_id'") or mysqli_error();
    while($got = mysqli_fetch_assoc($subcategory_query))
    {
    $subcategory_id = $got['subcategory_id'];
    $subcategory_name = $got['subcategory_name'];
    echo "<option disabled>--$subcategory_name</option>";

        // FOR ITEM
        $item_query = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM item WHERE subcategory_id='$subcategory_id'") or mysqli_error();
        while($got = mysqli_fetch_assoc($item_query))
        {
        $item_id = $got['item_id'];
        $item_name = $got['item_name'];
        echo "<option>----$item_name</option>"; 
        }
    }
}

echo "</select>";
```

My Concerns:

1. I don't actually know what's happening on why my second code is only doing the loop once and what's worse is it doesn't even display the sub category (the `maincategory_id='got_category_id'` beside the WHERE in my sql statement was only a placeholder and I tried replacing it by `maincategory_id='1'` just to check in hopes of it trying to at least check if it's displaying the sub category to no avail. I actually don't know the proper syntax to insert an integer inside a sql statement in Visual Studio but nevertheless, setting it to a value of '1' still doesn't display anything).
2. What is the proper syntax on inserting an integer inside a sql statement in Visual Studio? I researched and tried putting the & at the beginning and end of the variable but it isn't working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with the way you are building your second query.  Try using String.Format to proper embed you category ID into the query.

```
SqlCommand get_subcategory_name = new SqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT * FROM subcategory WHERE maincategory_id='{0}'", got_category_id), sc);
```

Comment: Thank you, this did the work for the syntax problem for the SQL although my main problem which is my combo box only displaying one row from the main category table is still unfortunately, unresolved.

Comment: This information might prove useful although I'm not sure if it's using the proper protocol but I tried adding a `cn.Close();` and `cn.Open();`  right below the `int got_category_id = Convert.ToInt32(dr2["maincategory_id"]);` and what it did was now I can see the sub categories from the main category BUT I still only see one main category when there's supposed to be four main categories so the loop still seems to only be running once or it might be running as intended but there might be problems on the cn connections that's making the next loop's queries fail.

Comment: You shouldn't have to refresh the connection between queries.  I recommend using the debugger to step through your code to make sure your queries are receiving what you expect.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm such a noob but how could I see the data my queries are getting from the debugger? For now, all I can see from my debugger are a bunch of items being loaded.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on your while loop to make sure it's iterating correctly (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5557y8b4.aspx).  You can also add watches on certain variables to check their values (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0taedcee.aspx).

Comment: I created two int variables named `number_of_maincategory_loops` and `number_of_subcategory_loops` and had the maincategory int variable to increment at the first line of the while loop of the main category and had the subcategory variable to increment at the first line of the while loop of the sub category and the results it game me where: The main category incremented once as it displayed a value of 1 and the sub category didn't increment as it displayed a value of 0.

Comment: If it worked without the subcategory loop, then it's possible you have an exception that's being suppressed.  Put a try-catch block around the code (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0yd65esw.aspx) and see if any exceptions are raised.  This could help troubleshoot further.

Comment: Thank You, I created a rich textbox and set its .text value to the catched exception and it displayed tons of errors and it looked like this: http://s17.postimg.org/xlvc0ar0v/try.png I didn't want to comment the errors here as it might be hard to read so I uploaded a picture of my current form.

Comment: Ok so you can only have one SqlDataReader open at a time.  What I would do it un-nest the loops.  Read all main categories in one loop.  Then loop through those categories with the sub-category query inside.  I'll update my solution to reflect this.

Comment: Oh crap, I finally did it. I added this code `MultipleActiveResultSets=True` on my connection string. Is this the right solution though? Just wondering.

Comment: That is definitely a valid solution.  Good find.  Glad we were able to talk through this.

Comment: Me too, thank you so much for your time in answering my questions. I actually learned a lot not only on my specific problem but also gained knowledge on debugging practices. I'll definitely keep these in mind next time I encounter a problem I couldn't explain.